# Control 12V relay by using Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, diodes, relay, electromagnet

I have an Arduino Mega, 12V relay module, and 12V external power supply.

I want to control relay state (on/off) by using Arduino I/O pins (5V).

Is it good idea to use following simple diagram?

There are two ***resistors***, ***Diode***, ***LED*** and ***Relay***.

*And how to choose those components for a given relay module?*

[image]

Comment: If the 5V supply also powers clocked digital circuitry, I would make T1 an optocoupled transistor with the 5V ground separated from the 12V ground.

Comment: You mention "relay module" but do you mean simply a bare "relay"? Because relay modules generally are modules with drivers relay already. Which relay or module you mean?

Comment: At the very least you don't want the kickback from the relay going through T1 onto your 5V signal.  Often trying to filter the spike causes ringing and even more parasitic pulses.  Opto-isolation is the sure way to isolate.

Comment: @Justme yes, I mean simple relay, something like that https://www.twinschip.com/Relay_12V-10A%20_5%20Pin-PCB

Answer (score 2):

That should work, however it's possible you may have problems due to coil-contact coupling, depending on your load, the relay, and your layout and wiring. It's better to have a separate supply for the relay and optocouplers adding additional isolation as modules often provide.

For a relay coil current of 100mA or less, just about any diode will do for D1. For example, 1N4005, 1N4148 etc. R2 determines your LED current. If (say) 3mA is enough you can use something like 3k\$\Omega\$. You do NOT need to run the LED at the maximum rated current, with modern LEDs a mA or two  is often enough to make it very visible without inadvertently blinding the user.

For the transistor, assuming a coil current of 100mA or less, you can use a jellybean transistor such as 2N4401, S8050. These have a high Ic rating, which ensures reliable operation when switching an inductive load (the relay coil).

The base resistor R1 determines the transistor drive. Typically 1/20 of the relay coil current is adequate. The sales blurb you link to does not specify the coil current exactly but says it will be 360mW or 450mW so the coil current should be 30mA or 37.5mA. So a 2k\$\Omega\$ base resistor will be fine for either.

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine, I'm using FET instead of BJT but otherwise it's the same circuit. Just make sure that your diode is connected correctly (otherwise your transistor releases the magic smoke), your transistor can handle the current, and use a properly sized resistor between Arduino and transistor.